# Get corresponding element from maximum of element wise 2d array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have four 2d arrays.
A = [[1,6], [3,5]]
A' = [[11,22], [33,44]] //each index value is related to corresponding index at A

similarly
B = [[5,2],[2,3]]
B' = [[55,66],[77,88]]

output
o/p = [[5,6], [3,5]]
o/p' = [[55,22],[33,44]] // how to get this output

I want to get element wise maximum from A and B, but I want to get the corresponding element
from A' and B'.
Doing a n^2 iteration is taking a lot of time.
numpy.maximum(A,B,A) can get me maximum value but how can I get corresponding elements from A' and B'.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
# Defining the arrays
A = np.array([[1,6], [3,5]])
A2 = np.array([[11,22], [33,44]])

B = np.array([[5,2],[2,3]])
B2 = np.array([[55,66],[77,88]])

# Get maximum of A and B. Do not do np.maximum(A, B, A), as this overwrites A.
C = np.maximum(A, B)

# Get indices where C = A and C = B.
A_indices = np.where(C == A)
B_indices = np.where(C == B)

# Get corresponding A2 and B2 values.
C2 = np.copy(C)
C2[A_indices] = A2[A_indices]
C2[B_indices] = B2[B_indices]
```

`C2` now has the values you want. Let me know if you have any questions.